# Multiple payment method for NopCommerce

Tags: payment, nopcommerce, .net-7.0

I want to prepare a payment plugin for NopCommerce where a virtual pos and a bank payment system are hosted in the same plugin. However, I am having trouble with how to do it, how to proceed.

I've updated the old versions of these methods, which were previously developed for NopCommerce and uploaded to github, and made them compatible with the current version. But when I tried to combine the two it didn't work. What should happen is that if the customer is going to make an installment payment method, he will automatically use the Virtual Pos payment method, and if he is going to make a payment with a single shot, he will automatically make the payment with the bank's payment method.